# Real and Imaginary part functions of a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we have a function of a complex variable whose real and imaginary parts  cannot be represented in cartesian Mongé $ z= F(x,y) $ form, but can only be represented as a  parametrized surface  $$ (x,y,z)=  f(u,v), g(u,v),h(u,v))\quad ?  $$

If not possible, why not? and if it is possible, please give some illustrative examples of such non-orthogonal parameterized cases.

For example for $ w=z^3$  the [monkey saddle](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=complex%20variable%20function&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE2K23rIrSAhWILY8KHSlSD88Q_AUICSgC&biw=1307&bih=635#imgrc=olUDzmSTZy6jJM:)  parts are both of Cartesian Mongé form only.

Comment: What do you mean "real and imaginary parts cannot be represented in Monge form"?

Comment: What is the connection here between the function and the surface? Are you looking at a real valued function? Then real and imaginary part makes no sense. If you are taking about a complex valued function it does not define a surface as a graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$. To me it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: E.g., $. w=z^2,   Re[w]= (x^2-y^2) , Im[w] =2 x y $  are hyperbolic paraboloid surfaces in Monge form. But Monge form is not the only way to represent a surface..